# Python - Convert the escape character of encoded string to %

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to encode a Chinese string

Here is the code:

```
chinese = "公主连结"
print(chinese.encode()) -> b'\xe5\x85\xac\xe4\xb8\xbb\xe8\xbf\x9e\xe7\xbb\x93'
```

the value it returns is an encoded object, and **'\x'** is an escape character, how can I manipulate with this object like a string

Here is what I expected:

```
input: b'\xe5\x85\xac\xe4\xb8\xbb\xe8\xbf\x9e\xe7\xbb\x93'
output: %E5%85%AC%E4%B8%BB%E8%BF%9E%E7%BB%93
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like URL encoding. You can [`urllib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) to get the desired result:

```
chinese = "公主连结"
import urllib.parse

print(urllib.parse.quote(chinese))
```

Result:

```
%E5%85%AC%E4%B8%BB%E8%BF%9E%E7%BB%93
```